# Issue with Ansible ternary filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I assume I'm doing something wrong here, but it would be helpful if someone could at least point me in the right direction. I have the following task:

```
- name: Set up users
  user: name={{ item.username }}
        groups={{ item.groups|join(',') }}
        comment={{ item.full_name }}
        shell=/bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ (extra_users is defined) | ternary(users + extra_users, users) }}"
```

The list `extra_users` is only sometimes defined, and when it isn't, the task fails with the error `"'extra_users' is undefined"`, which I thought the ternary would guard against. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that the parameters of the `ternary` filter are evaluated no matter what.

Anyway, there is a simplier solution:

```
with_items: "{{ users | union(extra_users | default ([])) }}"
```